# NodeJs javascript: wait until the previous object property is assigned before assigning the next property

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have code like this:

```
let result = {
  name: downloadNameFromInternetVerySlow(),
  isFamous: determineIfNameIsFamous(this.name);
}
```

```
const downloadNameFromInternetVerySlow = () => {
    path = "/home";
    const folders = fs.readdirSync(path).filter(file => fs.lstatSync(path).isDirectory());
    console.log(folders);
    return folders[0];
}
```

`downloadNameFromInternetVerySlow` can take a long time, meanwhile `determineIfNameIsFamous` depends on `downloadNameFromInternetVerySlow`'s result to return correct value.

How do I make sure `determineIfNameIsFamous` only runs after `downloadNameFromInternetVerySlow` is done?

Comment: These functions are apparently non-blocking and asynchronous.  They need an interface that allows you to know when they are complete using either an event, a returned promise or a callback you pass them.  We can't offer anything specific without seeing the actual code in those functions.

Comment: @jfriend00 See updates!

Comment: OK, based on that code, I've provided an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show is entirely synchronous so asynchronous results aren't actually the issue here like people were guessing.  The issue is that `this.name` cannot be used to refer to a prior property in an object literal definition for several reasons, not the least of which `this` isn't set to the object you want.

Instead, you can do this:

```
let result = {};
result.name = downloadNameFromInternetVerySlow();
result.isFamous = determineIfNameIsFamous(result.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `downloadNameFromInternetVerySlow` to a `Promise`(if not already). and then user `await` to wait till it finished. Otherwise you can use `Promise.then()`

(This should be inside an `async` function)

```
let name =  await downloadNameFromInternetVerySlow(),
let isFamous = determineIfNameIsFamous(this.name);

let result = {
  name,
  isFamous
}
```

Another method using `Promise.then`

```
let name, isFamous;
downloadNameFromInternetVerySlow().then(result => {
    name = result;
    isFamous = determineIfNameIsFamous(this.name);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `downloadNameFromInternetVerySlow` is asynchrononous (otherwise it would already work like you want), the solution is to use `await`.

Please note, to be able to do that, this code needs to be wrapped in an `async` function (or or top level with top level await available.)

```
async function getAndUseResult(){
  let result = {
    name: await downloadNameFromInternetVerySlow(),
    isFamous: determineIfNameIsFamous(this.name)
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
}
getAndUseResult();
```

Comment: `await` is highlighted with red in my IDE.

Comment: Please note, to be able to do that, this code needs to be wrapped in an async function (or or top level with top level await available.)
I'll update the answer

Comment: The OP's code is not asynchronous.  And, you can't use `this.name` inside an object literal because `this` isn't set to the object.  This won't work.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00, thanks for the note,
- Regarding the asynchronicity of downloadNameFromInternetVerySlow, I am assuming that's an error in the OP's code.
- Regarding `this.name`, this is working you can try it out in the chrome console:
```
const downloadNameFromInternetVerySlow = async ()=> 1;
const determineIfNameIsFamous = ()=>2
async function getAndUseResult(){

  let result = {
    name: await downloadNameFromInternetVerySlow(),
    isFamous: determineIfNameIsFamous(this.name)
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
}
getAndUseResult()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Async/await**

There’s a special syntax to work with promises in a more comfortable fashion, called “*async/await*”.

An async function returns a promise, like in this example:

```
const doSomethingAsync = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('I did something'), 3000)
  })
}
```

When you want to call this function you prepend await, and the calling code will stop until the promise is resolved or rejected. One caveat: the client function must be defined as async. Here's an example :

```
const doSomething = async () => {
  console.log(await doSomethingAsync())
}
```

Comment: The OP's code isn't asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function downloadNameFromInternetVerySlow(){
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Set timeout resolving...");
    return resolve("Sample Name");
  }, 5000))
}

function determineIfNameIsFamous(name){
  if(name === "Sample Name"){
    return true;
  }
  
  return false;
}

async function myFunc(){
   let result = {};
   result.name = await downloadNameFromInternetVerySlow();
   console.log(result);
   result.isFamous = determineIfNameIsFamous(result.name);

    return result;
}

myFunc().then(res => console.log("result : ", res))
```